# django-allauth Upgrade from 0.17 to 0.21

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm looking at upgrading allauth on a live application from version 0.17 to 0.21.

It seems like the documentation doesn't have detailed instructions on how to do that. There used to be on up until version 0.17 in the Readme file, but not in later versions.

Anyone out there that's done it? Or maybe I missed where that is documented?

For reference in case that matters, Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.6 (at this point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README/documentation has been broken down into separate files. The upgrade notes listing issues relating to backwards compatibility resides in `docs/changelog.rst`. This is available online over at: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html

Comment: Hi @pennersr. Love your work, thank you, and thanks for pointing me in the direction. I see then that it's mainly a case of running the migrations in order (South in my case) and making sure I'm not using any of the functionality that's been deprecated/changed. Is that correct?